# Increase performance when searching on concatenated columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a 2008 SQL server, with a large table, and I need to do a COUNT DISTINCT query on multiple columns, combined. Some columns are varchar, and others are int.

The query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(datepart(yyyy, [HistDate]) as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm, [HistDate]) as varchar(2)) + '-1' AS [DateSelector], 
    [Document] AS [Document], 
    -- This is the bit that needs optimizing
    COUNT( DISTINCT(
    Document + 
    Reference + 
    CONVERT(varchar(20),BatchID) +              -- this is an int
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),ResetCount),'')) -- this is an int
FROM documents
GROUP BY
    CAST(datepart(yyyy, [HistDate]) as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm, [HistDate]) as varchar(2)) + '-1' AS [DateSelector], 
    [Document] AS [Document], 
ORDER BY ...
```

Currently this query takes 23 sec, whereas replacing the above COUNT with  COUNT(*) took a couple of seconds. I have tried adding a combined index which  yielded 0 improvement. What kind of optimization can I do to speed up the searching?

Comment: I would suggest creating a computed column for _DateSelector_ and indexing it. But this will also add overhead for DML operations. What is the modification/retrieval rate for table?

Comment: @VishalGajjar although this may help the performance a bit, the performance issue is elsewhere in the code according to the question and the title

Answer (score 0):

You can probably improve the time by using

```
group by datepart(yyyy, Zeitstempel), datepart(mm, Zeitstempel)
```

You can group on just the integers without the conversion and still use that in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Concatinating the columns doesn't improve performance.

Try this instead:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    [HistDate],
    [Document] AS [Document], 
    row_number() over (partition by Document, Reference + BatchID + ResetCount order by (select 1)) rn
  FROM documents
)
SELECT
  convert(char(8),dateadd(mm, 
    datediff(mm, 0, [HistDate]), 0), 126)+'1' AS [DateSelector], 
  [Document] AS [Document],
  count(*) as cnt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY
  -- note you cant name a column in group by
  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [HistDate]), 0),
  [Document]
```